# Migration at runtime with dynamic connection string

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, dbcontext

I'm working on a project where I create a database with its tables whenever a user creates an account.

I create a `CustomerDbContext` with dynamic connection string injection to change the connection string depending on the user. I'm working with EF Core and couldn't manage to create migration and update the database at runtime when trying to use HTTP request that once it's invoked the tables will be created on the database

I tried

```
DatabaseFacade.ExecutSql("CREATE TABLE.....");
```

and it worked and created the table once I called the HTTP method, but  it would better to be automated rather then hardcoding SQL commands.

This the HTTP action method:

```
[HttpPost("Create database")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateDatabase([FromBody]string connectionString)
{
    CustomerDbContext _customerDbContext = new CustomerDbContext(connectionString);

    _customerDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlAsync($"create table....");
         
    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, "Database Created");
}
```

And this the `CustomerDbContext`:

```
public class CustomerDbContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomerDbContext(string connectionString) : base() {
        CustomerDbConnectionString = connectionString.ToString();
    } 

    public string CustomerDbConnectionString { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(CustomerDbConnectionString);
    }

    // entity 
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hardcoding SQL doesn't differ much from hardcoding EF core query. Maybe less portable, but definitely not wrong or less "automatic" (whatever that means). But the real red flag is: why you create a table on demand, on request? Or why you change connection string per user? So weird.

Comment: Look at [Multi-tenancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy)